# Associating radio button with controller wrapper class..?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce-id, radio-button

I need to get the associated record. i.e with the radio button.I am using input type radio button for the same.please someone help with the code...

```
<apex:column >
    <apex:facet name="header">
        Action
    </apex:facet>
    <input type="radio" name="selection" value="{!m.isSelected}" /> 

 </apex:column>

<apex:column value="{!m.meet.Subject__c}">
    <apex:facet name="header">
        Subject
    </apex:facet>
</apex:column>
```

```
<apex:commandButton value="Invite To Meeting" action="{!inv}"/>
```

wrapper class

```
public list<meetInviteWrapper> meetwrapperlist{get;set;}
    public class meetInviteWrapper
    {
        public meeting__c meet{get;set;}
        public Boolean isSelected{get;set;}
        public meetInviteWrapper(meeting__c m)
        {
            meet=m;
            isSelected=false;
        }



 public void inv()
    {
    List<meeting__c> mList=new List<meeting__c>();
        for(meetInviteWrapper miw:meetwrapperlist)
        {
            if(miw.isSelected)
            {
                mList.add(miw.meet);
            }

        }
    System.debug('------------------------'+mList);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm

Use select radio component of vusualforce page to achieve your requirement than html tags.

Always prefer vusualforce tags as data binding is easier.Refer the above doc dig deeper

Comment: can you help me with my code...i want to use html select radio..??

Comment: So you want to show the selected value to user through that wrapper as read only or user can edit and change ?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately binding controller variables to native HTML input tags won't work.  You need to use an `apex:input****` tag for the controller to get your changes.

If you need to use standard HTML input tags you'll need to use apex remoting which provides a method for using javascript to call controller methods.  Then you'll need to wire up some javascript to a button that when calls grabs the input tag value and then passes it to the apex remoting method.